# Why cannot forward declare a scoped enum?

Tags: c++, c++11

The title is already the question.
More details: the standard enacts:

> If the enum-key is followed by a nested-name-specifier, the enum-specifier shall refer to an enumeration that
>   was previously declared directly in the class or namespace to which the nested-name-specifier refers (i.e.,
>   neither inherited nor introduced by a using-declaration), and the enum-specifier shall appear in a namespace
>   enclosing the previous declaration.

at 7.2, paragraph 4.
For example, this prohibits to forward-declare an enum defined inside a class:

```
struct S{
  enum foo{A, B};
};
```

now, `S` can be forward-declared, while `S::foo` not.

Question is about *why*. Is there a situation in which this rule can be a benefit? Why is it needed? Or, if you prefer: if the standard had not this rule, is there a situation in which the compiler would have a problem? Which one(s)?

Comment: You can forward declare an enum class

Comment: yes in general, not if it is defined _inside_ a class.

Comment: Can you forward declare classes inside classes? I've never seen that...

Comment: You can forward-declare an enum class inside a class, much like you do in namespaces: `struct S { enum class foo; }; enum class S::foo { A, B };`

Comment: @paddy that's because the class itself is a namespace, but I guess the OP wants to forward-declare an enum _out_ of its class.

Comment: That would indicate a very questionable program design.

Comment: @paddy That can indicate also curiosity and that's all. I would not judge the question, for it's interesting anyway. ;-)

Comment: @skypjack, not everything that's interesting deserves to be implemented. Parts of a class cannot be forward declared outside of it, because they cannot be divorced. That's just sound design, and a reason to define a class to begin with. If a concept can be divorced from a class, it doesn't belong inside it to begin with.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I do not think the standards cares too much about the way I decide to (bad) design my code. It just technically describes the language, and there are reasons behind the rules. I was asking for those reasons. The posted sample was a real case that fails against that rule.

Comment: @fedino, for a rule to be in the standard it must have a reason (since it always makes the grammar more complex), and to facilitate bad design intentionally is not a good reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least, if forward-declare an enum was allowed, it would have created problems with template specializations like the one in the following example:

```
// somewhere in a .cpp

template<typename>
struct S;

enum S<int>::E;

// somewhere in a galaxy far, far away

template<typename>
struct S { enum class E {}; };

template<>
struct S<int> {};
```

How could the compiler know (and verify) that `enum S<int>::E;` is actually defined?

---

That said, even when you deal with namespaces you cannot do this:

```
struct X::A;
namespace X { struct A {}; }
```

But you can do this:

```
namespace X { struct A; }
namespace X { struct A {}; }
```

Using classes would result in a code like the following one:

```
struct A { enum E; };
struct A { enum E {} };
```

Anyway, this would violate the odr and it is not allowed.

---

Now, I'll try to give you my impression about the *why*.
If a forward-declaration of that type was allowed, you would have been allowed to give a *partial definition* of the containing class.
In other terms, consider this: `enum S::E`. This states firmly that `S` *contains* the enum class `E`, thus you are giving a clue about the definition of `S`. To speak not in *standardese* (that is far from being my natural language) you are partially defining `S`, thus the compiler should know that `S` has its definition somewhere *plus* it must have a definition for `E` too (either as part of the primary definition or as an out-of-class definition).
This would break the odr rules when the actual definition comes into view, so it cannot be allowed in any case, but as an exception of the basics rules of the language.
Moreover, this is a great source of headaches.

My two cents.

Comment: So you say that the act of forward-declaring a scoped `enum S::E;` would be sort of telling the compiler: expect a class `S`, and an enum inside that class; that is, I would define partially a class. But then, the true class definition violates ODR. And with templates, one could forward-declare something and then write a specialization in contradiction to it. That's _why_ it is forbidden. Did I catch your point?

Comment: More or less. The first is a _brutal_ explanation of what could be behind, but a language-lawyer will probably gives a better and completely different explanation sooner or later. The example that uses templates serves the purpose of showing what could happen if it was allowed. In that case, the linker would return an error, but the language allows it, so what could one do to work around it? Well, forbid those kinds of definition is a good point from which to start indeed. :-)

Answer (score 3):

A scoped `enum` is declared with `enum class` (or `enum struct`, not with `struct { enum …`. That would be an unscoped enumeration, in the scope of a class.

```
struct S {
    enum foo {A, B}; // Not a scoped enumeration.
};
```

A scoped enumeration can be forward-declared inside a class and defined outside:

```
struct S {
    enum class foo;
};

enum class S::foo { A, B };
```

However, you cannot declare a class member outside the class, unless it was already declared and you're defining it. Allowing member declarations outside would go against the principle that a `class { }` definition declares all the class members, that C++ classes are "closed."

Put another way, the rules for declaring and defining member scoped enumerations are essentially the same as for member functions or member classes.

Comment: The question could quickly become - _what's the reason for which you cannot declare anything outside a class_ (of course, apart for the fact that the standard says that)?

Comment: @skypjack Because, as I mentioned, a C++ class definition authoritatively declares the members of the class. This broad rule helps to implement the distinction between complete and incomplete classes.

Answer (score -1):

`enum Enumeration;` enum is **not** allowed to forward declare in header file.

`enum class Enumeration;` enum class is allowed to forward declare in header file.

Comment: `enum Enumeration : Type` is allowed to be forward declared